# Volume control per audio device on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, audio, speakers

I am used to the nice feature of MacOS X that has separate volume control per device (Speakers and Headphones). Is this possible on Windows 10 as well?

**Example**

When I mute the sound of my speakers, and plug in my Apple Earpods (3 connectors on the plug) via the 3.5 mm jack, the volume is set as it was the last time I used the headphones. And vice versa.

I hope that my example makes sense.

**Devices**

I have a *MacBook Air (Early 2015)*, and I try to achieve the separate volume control on my [Dell XPS 15 9570](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/xps-15-9570-laptop_service-manual_en-us.pdf).

The Dell laptop uses the Realtek (R) Audio driver.

**However...**

The audio playback device is called "Speakers/Headphones". So they are **not** two separate devices. I am plugging my headphones into the laptop directly. It looks like this:

[image: Speakers]

Comment: What computer do you have (type, model)? Are you plugging in headphones directly into the computer, or into e.g. external desktop speakers? Is Windows using "HD Audio" or "AC'97" drivers (in Device Manager)?

Comment: Can you answer the question about sound drivers in Device Manager as well?

Comment: Hmm, the driver should _specifically_ show up as either Realtek HD Audio or Realtek AC'97... And/or, maybe your firmware settings (BIOS) have an option to switch between the two? Also, do you have a Realtek control panel app thing anywahere in Windows?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any information about this in the BIOS. According to the Dell website, the XPS uses Realtek HD Audio.

Comment: 1) When responding to a Comment, please click on [edit] and put the requested information in the question. All information about the issue should be in the Question where all may see it. Also, please click on the grey (x) and delete your Comments to make room for more. 2) Are your headphones Bluetooth, USB-connected, or using a 3.5mm multi-pole plug to attach? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Klinkenstecker_5-polig.jpg 3) If the latter, how many connectors are on the plug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research, I found the [Waves MaxxAudio Pro](https://www.dell.com/support/home/nl/nl/nldhs1/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=VWPKK&osCode=WT64A&productCode=xps-15-9570-laptop) software on the [Dell XPS 15 9570 Support](https://www.dell.com/support/home/nl/nl/nldhs1/product-support/product/xps-15-9570-laptop/drivers) page.

After installing this software, the volume is now different for each device. So if I mute the speaker sound, the headphones will not muted and vice versa.

There is still only one playback device, however, MaxxAudio controls the audio.

Thanks for researching the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try the free Microsoft Store app
[EarTrumpet](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/eartrumpet/9nblggh516xp?activetab=pivot:overviewtab),
a Volume Mixer replacement.

A review of it can be found in
[EarTrumpet for Windows 10: A Better Windows Volume Mixer](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/eartrumpet-windows-10-volume-mixer/).

Judging by the screenshot below, it seems that it can do devices as well as apps:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I have one device for both Speakers and Headphones. I only see one device in EarTrumpet.

Comment: It is possible that hardware-wise, one device piggy-backs on the other so you see only one. If that's the case, I don't see a solution.

Comment: I am afraid you're right :/

Answer (score 0):

First, let's enable the headphones as a separate device.
a) Click the Start button.
b) Type Sound in the Start Search Box.
c) In the Start Menu Options, choose Change Sound Card Settings.
d) Under the Playback Tab, right click and select Show Hidden Devices and Show Disconnected Devices.
e) Select Headphones and enable.

Then, we set up the device-specific output level.

Right-click on the speaker icon in the Tray and choose Playback devices.

[image: Playback Devices menu]

Then on the Playback tab,

[image: Playback Tab menu]

select one output device (e.g., Headphones, or Speakers). After selecting it, click on Properties.

[image]

Then, move the slider tab to adjust its relative volume level and click **OK** .

Comment: The volume keeps the same for both speaker and headphones.

Comment: Please try decreasing the speaker volume using the above instructions, but selecting your Speakers on the Playback tab.

Comment: I only have one device in the list (for both Speakers and Headphones). I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Since having multiple devices would resolve your issue, you could install a new device. In the answer from K7AAY the headphones are LOGITECH WIRELESS HEADPHONES. They would have to be installed as a device as opposed to simply plugging into the headphone jack of the soundcard.

Answer (score 0):

I am concerned that the driver-based approach is not ideal. The nearest alternatives include using a software switch with a key binding. This solution requires the use of software audio switchers (such as AudioSwitch, AudioSwitcher, NirSoft, etc.) that can be activated through key combinations.

Another option is to use hardware audio switchers, also known as audio switchers. However, this requires connecting both speakers and headphones to the same physical box and manually toggling between them. The closest you can currently get to automatic switching is with an audio switch headphone stand, but it is not currently available on the market. It may be worth keeping an eye on its development.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1199065)